# Updating UserControl children in DependencyProperty setter not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, data-binding, user-controls

I have a UserControl in my Silverlight application and for some reason, the DependencyProperty of a UserControl is not set if I bind it to a value in the view model. I spent several hours of debugging in a trial-and-error fashion now and I'm all out of ideas what to try next.

I can reproduce the issue in a new Silverlight project with

MainPage.xaml

```c#
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <local:MyCtrl HeaderText="{Binding HeaderText}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```c#
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public class Vm
    {
        public string HeaderText 
        { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Vm() { HeaderText = "My Header" };
        }
    }
}
```

MyCtrl.xaml (added as new "Silverlight User Control")

```c#
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MyCtrl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtHeader" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyCtrl.xaml.cs

```c#
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MyCtrl : UserControl
    {
        public MyCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(MyCtrl), null);

        public string HeaderText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
            set
            {
                // NEVER CALLED
                SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value);
                this.txtHeader.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the project is used "as is", i.e. no compiler options were changed and the server part is also left "as is".

Observations:

- I see that the getter of `Vm.HeaderText` is called during a binding
  operation but the setter of the `DependencyProperty` `MyCtrl.HeaderText` is never called.
- The TextBlock in MainPage below the custom control displays the bound value correctly.
- There are no compiler warnings.
- There are no exceptions thrown.
- There are no debug outputs while the application runs.

This feels like something important is silently failing where it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I can shed some light on your observations and assumptions:

- You **can** update child controls inside a `DependencyProperty` setter. Call your setter and see for yourself, the update will be performed. You falsely assume the binding engine is obliged to call your setter. Well, it just calls `SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, newValue);` on your control, no need to call the setter.
- Your observation is specified behaviour.
- As you figured out, the right way to do it is to use a propertyChanged callback.
- The property getter on your viewmodel `Vm.HeaderText` is called by the binding engine, because your viewmodel is no `DependencyObject` and HeaderText is no `DependencyProperty` so there is no `SetValue(...)` and no `GetValue(...)`
- You can't see any compiler warnings or exceptions, nor is anything silently failing, because there is nothing wrong with your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems like you cannot update the child controls inside a DependencyProperty setter (would be interesting to know why and if this is specified behaviour...)

Using this instead works:

```c#
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(MyCtrl), new PropertyMetaData(OnHeaderTextChanged));

public string HeaderText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnHeaderTextChanged(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = d as MyCtrl;
    ctrl.txtHeader.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
}
```